# Drupal Commerce cart page to enter items

Tags: commerce

I have a website I am working on, and I want to have a shopping cart page that is basically like a purchase order entry form, where a customer can enter the products he wants and then save it or post it, etc. In other words, so you don't have to go through the whole site selecting the products you want like a shopping cart, but rather just enter the item codes like you were writing out a purchase order. The website is for a producer basically and the customers are distributors.

I need to be able to enter products by item code or UPC (need both), and it would be a bonus if each user account could have a list attached to it where the customer could enter their own item codes for our products.

I hope this makes sense, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the module [Commerce Add to Cart Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras). This got me started. Also, the module [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) I used to show the quantity that was ordered last time.